# Where should I place sub-structures within a MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to build a controller that will enable the user to add/remove subcontent to an item.

Think of it like a document where you can add different types of sections, like headlines, paragraphs, images etc. (they each have their own attributes so they are in seperate tables in the SQL)

My question is where should I put the code to handle the different types of subsections within this "document controller"?

They are all attached to this "document"/entity through database relations, but should I make a "crudl" controller for each type or should I do a base kinda crudl and then let them all inherit this?

I've looked into "Models" and "service layers" - is that the right way to do it?

I am still rather new with MVC, using C# and ASP.net I was hoping for someone to give me a hint in the right direction.

Nb. please let me know if I should rephrase the question. Didn't know what to ask to get the right answer here.

Specs: I use EF 4.x and MVC3 will upgrade to latest when available, if needed.

In hope of some clever answers or guidance. Thanks in advance people. And yes, I have tried to Google too. Don't know what to search for, so I come here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where should I put the code to handle the different types of subsections within this "documentcontroller"?

The code for this would ultimately go into a *controller action* which you then handle and update the database accordingly. There are multiple ways of doing this, you could be generic e.g.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddSection(string type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case "HEADING":
            // add new heading to database
        case "PARAGRAPH":
            // add new paragraph to database      
    }
    return View(type);
}
```

Or you could be specific e.g.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddHeadingSection()
{
    // add to db
    return View("Heading");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddParagraphSection()
{
    // add to db
    return View("Parapgraph");
}
```

The above is just really pseudo code to give you a rough idea of how you could do it with minimal effort. IN a real life situation you will probably be posting extra information along with it e.g. `AddHeadingSection(HeadingModel model)`. It's really up to you how you go about implementing this.

Also, you might want to consider using AJAX over full postbacks it would make your app a bit slicker.

Comment: aaah, nice. Yes, I am considering AJAX too (jQuery) as I need the user to stay on the "document" while adding/removing/editing content. If I understand the return View("Heading") approach right, this will redirect the user each time, right?

Comment: @BerggreenDK `return View("Heading")` is simply returning the view for the action, the actual navigation happens when you post to the action itself i.e. `http://mydomain/Documents/AddHeadingSection`. The view returned here would be the new heading. So in your scenario, you would post via AJAX to those actions and you could returned the rendered HTML (after adding the paragraph to the DB).